# Html Agility Pack - loop through rows and columns

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am just getting involved on parsing some html files using C# language and HtmlAgilityPack.

I am trying to get for each row the two columns values to insert them into a database.
But running the following:

```
foreach (HtmlNode row in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr"))
    {
    foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("//td"))
    {
    Console.WriteLine(cell.InnerText);
    }
    }
```

I got an error as I loop over all the td and not only the ones includes in the current tr.

My html looks like this:

```
<table>
        <tr>            
            <th align="center" width="50"><b>column 1</b></th>          
            <th align="center" width="210"><b>column 2</b></th>                 

        </tr>   



            <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <td align="left"> </td>             
                <td align="left"></td>                          

            </tr>   


            <tr bgcolor="#dddddd">
                <td align="left"> </td>             
                <td align="left"></td>                          

            </tr>   


            <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <td align="left"> </td>             
                <td align="left"></td>                          

            </tr>
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: I get no error. But i am expecting to get only two column for each row. Instead of that, each iteration I retrieve all the row part of that document.

Answer (score 0):

just to let you know that I have updated the code which works well but do not looks so good at all:

```
j = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr").Count;
                    if (j != 0)
                    {

                        for (int i = 2; i < j; ++i)
                        {
                            for (int k = 1; k < 3; k++)
                            {
                                HtmlNodeCollection row = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/table/tr[" + i + "]/td[" + k + "]");
                                Console.WriteLine("nb or row" + row.Count);


                                Console.WriteLine(row[0].InnerText);
                                //Console.Read(); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

If you have any idea to enhance this code it would be great.

Thanks,
Damien

Comment: You're better posting this in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this

```
var rows = doc.DocumentNode
              .SelectNodes("//tr")
              .Select((z, i) => new
                  {
                    RowNumber = i,
                    Cells = z.ChildNodes.Where(c => c.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element) })
              .ToList();

rows.ForEach(row => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", row.RowNumber, string.Join(", ", row.Cells.Select(z => z.InnerText))));
```